# For a set of integers, get all subsets that exceed a value but do not include unnecessary members

Tags: python, set, knapsack-problem

##### The Problem

I'm trying to come up with an *efficient* means to generate all subsets of a set of integers, such that the subsets exceed some value **N** but do not contain any superfluous members.

That is to say, once a set exceeds **N**, no additional members should be added. Once you've identified a subset that exceeds N, that subset should not be included in any subsequent subsets.

##### Example

Take for example the following set:

`[1, 2, 5, 1, 3]`

For a value of **N = 6**, the solution is:

`[5, 2] [5, 1, 1] [5, 3] [3, 2, 1, 1]`

These are all the sets that can be constructed such that no set contains a member that is unneeded to exceed N.

`[5, 2, 1]` is not included, for example, because `[5, 2]` already exceeds **N**, and thus any new set which also includes `[5, 2]` as a subset is redundant.

##### Generating All Sets That Exceed N

I have the following code which can be used to generate all subsets which exceed some value **N**

```
from collections import Counter

def solve(nums, target):
    counts = sorted(Counter(nums).items())
    reserve = sum(nums) - target
    
    if reserve <= 0:
        return []
    return list(_solve(counts, reserve, []))

def _solve(counts, reserve, prefix):
    if not counts:
        yield tuple(prefix)
        return
    
    val, max_count = last = counts.pop()
    
    prefix.extend([val] * max_count)
    yield from _solve(counts, reserve, prefix)
    
    for count in range(1, max_count + 1):
        prefix.pop()
        if reserve - count * val > 0:
            yield from _solve(counts, reserve - count * val, prefix)
    
    counts.append(last)
```

However, I'm not sure how to modify this in way that *efficiently* eliminates or avoids calculating the unnecessary subsets (the one that exceed **N** and include a member not required to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different way to solve this problem.

```
def find_subset_sums_greater_than_n(lst,n):
    lst.sort(reverse=True)
    all_subsets,subset = [],[]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        subset_sum = lst[i]
        subset.append(lst[i])

        for j in range(i+1,len(lst)):
            if subset_sum > n:
                if len(all_subsets)==0 or subset != all_subsets[-1]:
                    all_subsets.append(subset[:])
                if len(subset) > 1:
                    subset_sum -= subset[-1]
                    subset.pop()
                else:
                    break  # stop inner loop if lst[i] > N 
            subset.append(lst[j])
            subset_sum+=lst[j]

        if subset_sum > n and (len(all_subsets)==0 or subset != all_subsets[-1]) :
            all_subsets.append(subset)
        if sum(lst[i+1:]) <= n:   # Stop early if sum of remaining elements doesn't exceed n
            break
        subset=[]
    return all_subsets
```

Runtime Analysis:

The sorting takes `O(nlogn)`, the outer for loop runs worst case `n` times. For each iteration of outer loop inner loop runs worst case `n` times and the sum function runs `n` times worst case, so total for the algorithm is `O(n^2)`. (`n` is the length of the list).

The only two improvements are as follows:

1. When either `N` is larger than the sum of several elements at the end of the list, since the outer loop will break early in this case. Using your example, for `N = 8`, the algo stops once `lst[i]=3` since `3+2+1+1 < 8`, so we save checking `[3],[3,2],[3,2,1]...,[2],[2,1]...` and so on.
2. When `N` is smaller then several elements at the beginning of the list. Here it will also skip several subsets by breaking the inner loop runs early, since we have exceeded `N` already, so we can skip all subsets that contain more than just that number. Using your example, for `N = 2`, we get `[5]` and `[3]` and then skip all subsets that are larger than length `1` and that contain `5` or `3`.

Despite these improvements, the runtime is still `O(n^2)` since we can choose an `N` that makes this algorithm approach the worst case scenario.